Horizontal Opicalflow
I can get the X-axis (horizontal) flow through the following:
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(
            self.prev_gray, curr_gray, None,
            pyr_scale=0.5, levels=8, winsize=3,
            iterations=1, poly_n=3, poly_sigma=1.2,
            flags=0
            )
horizontal_flow = flow[...,0]

since I am only interested ion the horizontal movement, is there a faster more effecient way to calculate it?
the objects in the scene move horizontally in front of a stationary camera

you could repurpose "block matching" algorithms from stereo vision, such as the SGBM algorithm. I think with that one you can lock down the search directions.
